# If I turn off iCloud Photos on my phone, will the photos I take show up on other devices?

Tags: icloud, photos

If I turn off iCloud Photos on my phone, will the photos I take show up on other devices linked to the same Apple ID?

Comment: They will not show, as they will not sync with your iCloud account.

Comment: It depends: if you still have (the now being phased out) Photo Stream, pictures, but not movies should still show up on other devices.  Also live photos won't be live, transferred that way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Keeping photos in sync between phone and laptop (without iCloud?)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/402652/keeping-photos-in-sync-between-phone-and-laptop-without-icloud)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you will be keeping your iCloud account after turning off photos in iCloud and all your devices will remain signed in to iCloud with the same account, up to 1000 photos (not videos) you have taken in the last 30 days will be visible in those devices as part of Apple’s My Photo Stream service which is free. However, once a photo gets older than 30 days, it will be removed from My Photo Stream, remaining available only on the device it is taken.

For more information on this service, see the “[My Photo Stream](https://support.apple.com/en-au/HT201317)” Apple support webpage.